# VBA macro to select cell based on row and column criteria

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm trying to create a macro that runs with a custom user form shown below. My ultimate goal is to have the Expenditure Category radial select the sheet in the file, then have the PO Number field search column A of the selected sheet to find a match, then subsequently have the Week Ending Date field search row 7 to find a match for the date entered. Where these two intersect (i.e. CN72) is where I want to input what is put in Accrual Amount. I have no idea about how to go about doing this, so any help would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a loop inside another loop...I might use something like this..

```
x = 1
z = 1
datexx = [input]
POnumber = [input]
do

  do

if Sheets("[name]").Range("[column]" & z) = Sheets("[name]").Range("[column]" & x) then
'do your stuff here
end if
z = z +1 
loop until isempty(Sheets("[name]").Range("[A column that is never empty for all data]" & z) 
x = x+ 1
loop until isempty(Sheets("[name]").Range("[A column that is never empty for all data]" & x)
```

Comment: I apologize for my lack of inexperience, but how do I address the radial answer activating the selected sheet. For example, if I want radial "Equipment" to activate Sheet8 (Equip), how would that change the above code?

Comment: What do you have so far in your user form? If this category is a selection from a list of selections... Or a textbox? You would just do assign name = selected category at the top then sheets(name) everywhere you see it.. an image of your current user form or your attempts would help communicate.

Comment: I tried adding an image of my userform but my reputation isn't high enough. The sheet would be selected from one of four radial buttons in a frame. I'm not partial to this form, so if a listbox would work better, I'm open to that. But it lists the four different types, each corresponding to a sheet. So for example, radial button Equipment would need to be activate Sheet8 (Equip) when chosen.